# Java - how are method overrides with compatible arguments handled?

Tags: java, methods, overloading

Take the following code:

```
public interface InterfaceA {    }
public interface InterfaceB {    }
public class Abba implements InterfaceA, InterfaceB {    }

public class MainThingy {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Abba abObj = new Abba();
        int result = MainThingy.doStuff(abObj);
    }
    private static int doStuff(InterfaceA param) {
        System.out.println("method A");
    }
    private static int doStuff(InterfaceB param) {
        System.out.println("method B");
    }
}
```

Since both doStuff() methods would take the Abba argument, it isn't clear which one will be called. How does the Java compiler and/or JVM handle this?

Comment: Since you already have the code, *what happened when you tried it*? Take that information and incorporate it into the post (title and body) as well as using it to refining a search on the subject...

Comment: Sorry, I suppose I was searching with the wrong terms. Also, you're absolutely right, I should have tried to compile it. I don't know why that didn't occur to me as I was writing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple. This code doesn't compile due to the ambiguous reference.

```
$ javac MainThingy.java 
MainThingy.java:4: reference to doStuff is ambiguous, both method doStuff(InterfaceA) in MainThingy and method doStuff(InterfaceB) in MainThingy match
        MainThingy.doStuff(abObj);
                  ^
1 error
```

Comment: It also won't compile because `doStuff` doesn't return an `int`.

Comment: Part 2) What role, if any, does the JVM play in determining/selecting overloads?

Comment: The java language spec specifies in precise detail all the overload behavior. The JVM implements it.

Comment: @Asaph `javac` didn't miss it.  It just hadn't gotten there yet.

Comment: @TimPote Apparently so. In my experience `javac` reports multiple errors if present. It doesn't stop after the first one. I guess this one was fatal enough to bail on.

Comment: @Asaph In _my_ experience, javac has multiple "rounds" of error checking. If it gets, say, a brace error (forgot to close your new if statement) then it won't report anything in the later "rounds"; it will report multiple errors if they occur in the same "round". So here, the arguments were checked in an earlier round than the returns.

Comment: @Asaph I was going for "the JVM doesn't do overloading". Overloaded method signatures must be unambiguously selected at compile-time (even though the signatures *look* the same in code, they are two distinct methods) and are thus an artifact of the *language*.